# Формы в yii. тэг [select] вместо id записи из связанной таблицы. Как?

Tags: crud, связи, формы, yii

Привет всем!

В джанго-админке есть такая клевая штука, как автоматическая генерация форм. Так вот, если в модели есть ссылка на другую модель, в форме это поле представляется как выпадающий список со значениями из связанной таблицы.

Как подобное сделать в формах Yii? Можно прям в шаблоне делать запрос к БД, но это не красиво, и Я так полагаю, неправильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google + меньше минуты времени = http://www.dbhelp.ru/by-example-chtml-dropdownlist/page/

Добавлю, что сам Yii пока что не умеет генерить select, надеюсь в след версии это поправят.

Comment: Эх, этот способ Я знаю. Я думал, что есть способ по красивее. Спасибо и на том)